# Slicing large lists based on input

Tags: python, list, slice

If I have multiple lists such that

```
hello = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13]

bye = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14]
```

and the user inputs `3`

is there a way to get the output to go back 3 indexes in the list and start there to get:

```
9 10

11 12 

13 14
```

with tabs `\t` between each space.

if the user would input `5`

the expected output would be

```
5 6

7 8

9 10

11 12

13 14
```

I've tried

```
for i in range(user_input):
    print(hello[-i-1], '\t', bye[-i-1])
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(hello)-user_input, len(hello)):` `print(hello[i], '\t', bye[i])`

Answer (score 4):

Just use negative indexies that start from the end minus the user input (`-user_input`) and move to the the end (`-1`), something like:

```
for i in range(-user_input, 0):
    print(hello[i], bye[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `zip` solution, but one-lined:

```
for h, b in zip(hello[-user_input:], bye[-user_input:]):
    print(h, b, sep='\t')
```

Avoids converting the result of `zip` to a `list`, so the only temporaries are the slices of `hello` and `bye`. While iterating by index can avoid those temporaries, in practice it's almost always cleaner and faster to do the slice and iterate the values, as repeated indexing is both unpythonic and surprisingly slow in CPython.

Answer (score 0):

Use negative indexing in the slice.

```
hello = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13]

print(hello[-3:])

print(hello[-3:-2])
```

output

```
[9, 11, 13]
[9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` the two lists and use `itertools.islice` to obtain the desired portion of the output:

```
from itertools import islice
print('\n'.join(map(' '.join, islice(zip(map(str, hello), map(str, bye)), len(hello) - int(input()), len(hello)))))
```

Given an input of `3`, this outputs:

```
5 6
7 8
9 10
11 12
13 14
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` to return a lists of tuple where the i-th element comes from the i-th iterable argument.

```
zip_ = list(zip(hello, bye))
for item in zip_[-user_input:]:
    print(item[0], '\t' ,item[1])
```

then use negative index to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to analyze the data

I think using *pandas.datafrme* may be helpful.

```
INPUT_INDEX = int(input('index='))

df = pd.DataFrame([hello, bye])
df = df.iloc[:, len(df.columns)-INPUT_INDEX:]
for col in df.columns:
    h_value, b_value = df[col].values
    print(h_value, b_value)
```

console

```
index=3
9 10
11 12
13 14
```